# C++ String insert on a varying position

Tags: c++, string

I have to basically insert a character that I input with the Keyboard into a string of alphabetically ordered characters, and that character has to be placed in the right alphabetical position. But I cannot use the `std::sort` function or any kind of sorting since the string is already sorted and I need to insert the character directly in the correct position.
I did a for loop and an if to compare but I get an error when inputting the character...

```
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
{
    if (myChar < myString[i])
    {
        myString.insert(myString[i], 1, myChar);
    }

}
```

can you help me figure out what I am missing ?

The error I am getting is R6010 - abort() has been called.

Also for `myString.insert(i, 1, myChar);` nothing happens when I input the character.

EDIT: I just had to add the break; line at the end of the loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myString.length(); i++)
{
    if (myChar < myString[i])
    {
        myString.insert(i, 1, myChar);
        break;
    }


}
```

Comment: Might help if you explained what error you're getting

Comment: Reading e.g. [this `insert` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert) might help you. Or, really, *any* kind of reference or documentation.

Comment: You're using `myString[i]` as an index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop after your insertion must be terminated with break, because maybe your condition satisfies many times after first time.

You better append myChar and then resort myString.

Comment: I just had to add the break; line xD completely went over my head. thanks bud.